# How do you explode more than one list column with different lengths

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have come across this issue I'm having so I checked to see whether there were any similar questions posted, but all of the solutions are referring to lists which have the same amount of items within or just one single list column, but my dataset contains 2 list columns both of different lengths.

Lets say I have this dataset:

```
{ 
    "_id" : 43, 
    "userId" : 5, 
    "Ids" : [
        "10", 
        "59", 
        "1165", 
        "1172"
    ], 
    "roles" : [
        "5f84d38", "6245d38"
    ]
}
```

**Current Dataframe:**

```
                 _id     userId                        Ids                     roles
                  43          5           [10,59,1165,1172]         [5f84d38,6245d38]
```

How do I explode both lists so that it will give this output below.

**Desired Dataframe:**

```
                 _id     userId                        Ids                     roles
                  43          5                         10                   5f84d38
                  43          5                         59                   5f84d38 
                  43          5                       1165                   5f84d38
                  43          5                       1172                   5f84d38
                  43          5                         10                   6245d38
                  43          5                         59                   6245d38
                  43          5                       1165                   6245d38
                  43          5                       1172                   6245d38
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

d = { 
    "_id" : 43, 
    "userId" : 5, 
    "Ids" : [
        "10", 
        "59", 
        "1165", 
        "1172"
    ], 
    "roles" : [
        "5f84d38", "6245d38"
    ]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=d.keys())
rows = []
for role in d['roles']:
    for _id in d['Ids']:
        df = df.append({"_id" :d["_id"], "userId": d["userId"], "Ids":_id, "roles": role}, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Would you happen to know a dynamic way of doing this without explicitly specifying the column names?

Comment: It depends. You can see which keys have more than one element (e.g. using len(d[key]) ), and make a loop for those. Or, you can make a loop for ALL keys, and the ones than contain only one element will be accessed only once.
But these really are just hacks, I don't understand exactly your general case.. But I hope I helped you in some way, or at least gave you some insight.